# ANR while inflating layout in which upload image from url in android?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-imageview, android-inflate

I m trying to show image from URL but while showing image when i touch the screen or want to scroll than it show **app not responding**.

**What i do on my code:-**

1. Inflate four different-2 type of xml on main screen in which I'm showing images which comes from URL.Its works fine but problem is my above heading of question.

   ```
    _______________________
   |           |           |
   |           |           |
   |     1     |     2     |
   |           |           |
   |_______________________|
   |           |           |
   |           |           |
   |     3     |     4     |
   |           |           |    
    _______________________
    many more inflating layout
   ```

   In above 1 , 2 , 3 and 4 xml some stuff with imageview.
2. I'm trying so many link or lib file which shown below :

   [SmartImageView](http://loopj.com/android-smart-image-view/)
    [LazyLoader](https://github.com/thest1/LazyList)
    [Universal Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader)

   Above mentioned LIB file working fine when using Gallery or listview but not works fine on my case.

many more which available when im doing google...

Code:

```
for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
{
    // inflate one ofI'm trying so many link or lib file which shown below :- four type of xml and run below Asyntask
}
```

Asyntask in which shown image and using Universal Image Loader to display image on imageview

```
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            ControlPage.imageLoader.init(ImageLoaderConfiguration.createDefault(act));
            ControlPage.imageLoader.displayImage(values_of_book,cover_image_book_link, options);


        }
    }
```

Above im using **Universal Image Loader** lib file for showing image and **its works fine on gallery view or list view** but not in my case.

image which occure while loading image from url and we can touch the screen

[image]

Comment: it may create problem due to size of images . use any imageloader library.

Comment: @ManojPal im using "Universal Image Loader" lib for download. If u know better dan this so please let me know.

Comment: If, as you say, the problem comes when you touch the screen, then I think you need to show us the code for `ClickOnUserProfile.clickOnUserProfile`, and in addition LogCat output. The code you have currently shown does not help us find your problem.

Comment: @KenY-N on this funtion ClickOnUserProfile.clickOnUserProfile i'm start new activity but thing is that when ever i scroll the screen then above ANR is occur ....

Comment: Are you executing Asynctask inside for loop ?

Comment: @kaushaltrivedi inside the onPostExecute method

Comment: you need to download the images in doInBackground() method..theres no use of Asynctask if u are not doing background processes in the background method...do the downloading in doInbackground() and do the UI interaction in onPostexecute method..also you should put the stacktrace that would help figure out what exactly is causing the problem

Comment: I'M USING Universal Image Loader SO NO NEED TO DOWNLOAD IMAGE ON DO IN BACKGROUND IT HANDLE AUTOMATICALLY ON GALLERY OR LIST VIEW BUT NOT IN MY CASE

Comment: Why do you initialize the downloader in the post execute? I think this should be done only once per the whole application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those Image load libraries usually does load no the same Thread if the resource is already downloaded. This may freeze your screen, force async load of those and you will not receive any ANR.